# Can I build a jQuery prototype function without checking if jQuery has fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I create a jQuery prototype in this way:

```
<script 
   src="/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" 
   type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script src="/Scripts/common/layout/jquery.fn.buildTableOfContent.js"></script>
```

When the buildTableOfContents.js file looks like this:

```
$.fn.buildTableOfContent = function () {
    "use strict";
    var h2 = this.find('h2');
    if (h2.length > 0) {
    .....
```

What I am concerned about is does the prototype function build depend on jQuery 
being completely loaded and with my file like this will the buildTableOfContents file
always get executed after the jQuery has fully loaded?

Comment: Since you arent loading the script asynchronously, jquery will always be completly loaded before your custom javascript file (assuming yo load them in the order above).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your code requires `$` to be defined, and hence jQuery to be loaded. And yes, putting the jQuery include before your plugin include guarantees that jQuery will be available when your plugin is created.

Upon reaching a script block, the browser will halt any further rendering of the page, download the external document, execute the code inside it, before proceeding to render the rest of the page. This is why you want to put your script blocks just before closing the body (so that the rest of the page will render regardless of blocking requests).